# How to clean windows as if restarted?

Tags: windows, memory, batch-file, speed, temporary-files

Is there a way to make windows run as or almost as fast is if first started but without the need to restart it ??

I was thinking there must be a way of deleting all the junk and tmp files, cleaning the ram, register files, kill ghost programs, etc. Which is what happens when you restart it.

A .bat file with all the commands to clean it will be needed, I run it, at it would become noticeable faster, I'm not asking for a fresh start, but for a considerable improvement. Is it possible ??

Comment: If you have a noticable degrade of performance over runtime I guess something is  wrong with your system. Maybe memory, free space or unbalanced system components. How long does your system usually run?  What about cleanmgr?

Comment: How long do you normally leave your computer up between reboots? As LotPings mentions performance drops requiring a reboot would indicate memory leaks and other problems. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: One problem is that all of the flotsam isn't conveniently labeled as crap. You can't issue a single command like "delete crap".  If you knew ahead of time what the offending programs were, you could fix the cause.   At best, you would need to run a program or series of programs or scripts to deal with classes of stuff, white/black lists, etc.  And that doesn't fix the underlying problem of why the stuff is there in the first place.  Logging out and logging back in can accomplish much of what you want and is a little faster than rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

- First, use regular Windows cleanup: right-click on the boot (C:) drive in Explorer and select *Properties*.  On the *General* tab select *Disk Cleanup*. Wait until the first scan (not actual cleanup) completes, select *Clean up system files*, and let it run, perhaps for hours. Note that this may remove as much as "4 TB" or so of *links*, thought the disk size may be far smaller. Go figure...
- Second, on the *Tools* tab of the C: *Properties*, select *Optimize*. Select all drives, then *Analyze*, then *Optimize*. Again, be prepared to wait for it to finish.
- Third, remove any programs and toolbar add-ons you do not use. Some browser add-ons are particularly pernicious.
- Fourth, try using a third-party cleaning tool such as *[CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)* and/or *[PrivaZer](https://privazer.com/)*. These are better at cleaning up disk space than speeding up a PC, though.
- Fifth, disable any MS background tasks that continually use the internet bandwidth, including live tiles such as news and weather. In addition, turn off MS incoming ads with tools such as [Shutup10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10).
- Finally, in *Windows Control Panel*, *System Properties*, *Advanced* tab, select *Performance Settings*. On the *Advanced* tab, change *Virtual memory* according to the amount of RAM present. This is too involved to  cover here, but in brief, my experience has been that for machines with 4 GB *or more* of RAM and HDD, the best performance was achieved with 4 GB of virtual memory (page file size), set manually. With a solid state drive, a larger page file is usable.